# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation. error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut Spring AOP

Tags: java, controller, aop

I'm facing an error that mentioned below, related to Spring Aspect Oriented Programming.

```
2022-05-06 17:26:44 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.java Line 826: Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/ProjectingArgumentResolverRegistrar.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut
```

Previously I used applicationContext.xml file. But after I added @Configuration annotation to the CommonController class and removed applicationContext.xml file. I just search some solutions and apply to my code, but still didn't clear my issue.  Hope your support and attach my code below, thank you.

Aspect.java

```
package com.intervest.medical.aggregator;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Aspect {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void aspect() {
        logger.info("FFFFFFFFFFFFF {} | request {} | registerParam {}", "RETURNVALUE", "request", "registerParam");
    }
}
```

CommonController.java

```
    package com.intervest.medical.aggregator.controller;
    
    import com.healix.blackboxdirect.ArrayOfString;
    import com.healix.blackboxdirect.DirectServiceSoap;
    import com.intervest.medical.engine.domain.*;
    import com.intervest.medical.engine.service.*;
    import com.intervest.medical.engine.util.*;
    import com.intervest.medical.engine.constants.RegisterError;
    import com.intervest.medical.engine.constants.RegisterState;
    import com.intervest.medical.engine.dto.ValidationDTO;
    import com.intervest.medical.engine.dto.XmlResultDTO;
    import com.intervest.medical.engine.enums.Stub;
    import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import java.util.*;
    
    @Controller
    @Aspect
    @Configuration
    public class CommonController {
    
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommonController.class);
    
        @Autowired
        ScreeningProxyService screeningProxyService;
    
        @Autowired
        MedicalDataKeeperService medicalDataKeeperService;
    
        @Autowired
        private MedicalUrlService medicalUrlService;
    
        @Autowired
        private MedicalConstantsService medicalConstantsService;
    
        @Autowired
        private MedicalConfigService medicalConfigService;
    
        @ResponseBody
        @Pointcut("within(com.intervest.medical.aggregator.Aspect.*)")
        @Before("reScreenAndGetXmls(@RequestBody RegisterParam registerParam)")
        @RequestMapping(value = "/medical/screeningData/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public RegisterResult doScreen(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody RegisterParam registerParam) {
    
            ValidationDTO intiValidationDTO = screeningProxyService.initialValidation(registerParam, false);
            if (!intiValidationDTO.isSuccess()) {
                return new RegisterResult(null, intiValidationDTO.getErrMsg());
            }
    
             ........................
}
```

Application.java

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        springApplication.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        Environment environment = springApplication.run(args).getEnvironment();
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        Aspect e = (Aspect) applicationContext.getBean("Aspect");
        e.aspect();

}
```

Comment: It would be better if an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could be shared . I would recommend you separate out the aspect code from the controller class. The code shared is a mix-up of a lot of unrelated annotations which itself makes it hard to read and understand the cause. Do share a minimal code which reproduces the issue .

Comment: Your code is a mash-up of things which ought to be separated. For instance, your class `Aspect` has no `@Aspect` or `@Component` annotations and does not do anything even remotely resembling an aspect. What is its purpose? Please also rename it, so as not to confuse the class name with the `@Aspect` annotation. Even worse, `CommonController` is 3 things at once: a controller, an aspect and a configuration class. Those 3 should be separate. Also, a response body is not a pointcut and an aspect advice at the same time. This is just total chaos, with all due respect.

Comment: Please be polite enough to reply, if other community members spend time, commenting on your question, trying to help you. If you do not answer any questions, how can we know if your problem is solved or you have any follow-up problems when adjusting the code according to our hints? The question will remain open forever, which is not helpful to anyone.

Comment: Extremely sorry @kriegaex. Previous couple of days, I was not active in this platform. I have added the answer for my issue. Thanks for your advice and the support.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. There was an issue with my Aspect class. I didn't add relevant annotations to that class. I was able to solve the issue after adding those annotations to the Aspect class and removing unwanted annotations from controller class.

```
 package com.intervest.medical.aggregator;
    
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    
    @org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
    @Component
    public class Aspect {
        private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
        public void aspect() {
            logger.info("FFFFFFFFFFFFF {} | request {} | registerParam {}", "RETURNVALUE", "request", "registerParam");
      

  }
}
```

Comment: Like I said, an aspect should not have any `@Configuration` annotation. Spring e.g. creates different types of proxies for `@Configuration` vs. `@Component` The annotations are not interchangeable and should not be combined on the same class either because of their fundamentally different semantics. The annotation also sends a false message: Your aspect does not contain any Spring config but is a simple component configured by Spring. I also reiterate: Please nename the aspect so as to avoid the `Aspect` name collision your are trying to heal with the fully qualified annotation class name.